# Apache :mod-status shown too larg requests for images directory

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, ddos

I use Apache on my server ,

My server stopped multi times cause too large requests for images directory! (my server not for download images)

different IP and Proxies make this attack ,I can't stop them

I check **mod-status** an shown more than **1000 requests** for image directory ! with multi **IP and proxies** (300 IP and more) !!

How can I solve this problem and stop this IP and proxies??

***Note:*** my server is Windows
and I use **mod-evasive** but not stopped them because multi IP not one

Comment: Take a look at fail2ban.

Comment: my server is Windows , not Linux 
and I use  mod-evasive @user430214